# paginate the class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please help me with pagination of this method

my method is this one

controller

#

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id]) 
  @posts = @topic.posts.find(:all ,:order=> 'id')
end
```

views

#

```
%div{:style=>"margin: 0 auto;"}
  %table.sortable.style2{:cellpadding=>5}
    %thead
      %tr
        %td{:width => "25%",:align => "center",:style => "font-weight: bold;"}Posted By
        %td{:width => "75%",:style => "font-weight: bold;"}Comments
    %tbody  
      - for post in @posts 
        %tr
          %td{:align => "center"}
            &nbsp
            %div{:width=>"5px" , :style=>"border: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 232);background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);width: 60px; height:60px;" }
              - if post.posted_by.image 
                = image_tag(post.posted_by.image.public_filename(),:width => "60px", :height => "60px",:align=>"center")
            %div{:style => "font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"}
              = post.posted_by ? post.posted_by.firstname : "<em>Unknown User</em>" 
              %br
            %div{:style => "font-style: italic;"}
              Posted on 
              = post.created_at.strftime('%d of %B %Y ')
              = post.created_at.strftime('at %H:%M')  
          %td{:valign => "top"}
            =post.body
```

Comment: What is you problem exactly ? there are no really question on it.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is really simply with mislav's [will_paginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/). Read the [installation instructions](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/installation), and the example in the [README](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/README.rdoc) file. The example covers almost *exactly* what you're aiming at.

For your scenario, you want to start by editing your `Post` model class. Specify the amount of posts to view per page:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 10
end
```

You can use the paginate method on an association too, so this will work:

```
@posts = @topic.posts.paginate :order => 'id'
```

Then, in your view, where you want to show the page links, simply do:

```
= will_paginate @posts
```